# Table seems lost when I try to  I define a 'Campus' model in rails and set the plural name myself

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I need a table whos name is Campus. But rails interprets that as plural, messing everything up.
So I did a [little research](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5198) and they suggest to add an inflection like this:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular /^(campus)(es)?$/i, '\1'
  inflect.plural   /^(campus)$/i, '\1es'
end
```

I have added this in the initializers/inflection.rb file. 
I created a new migration to drop the table and create a new one again called Campus, expecting to have the problem solved, but now I can't get the table Campus in the console:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.10)
1.9.2p290 :001 > Campus
 => Campus(Table doesn't exist)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem? 
Thanks for your help

My campus model is:

```
class Campus < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :university_id

  has_many :pois, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :market_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ads_points, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :university
end
```

Comment: What is the name of your table? `campuses`?

Comment: Campus is the name of the table.

Comment: Rails convention is that the table name is `campuses`. So you have to either change the table name or add `set_table_name 'Campus'` to your `Campus` model.

Comment: Please show your model code in the app/models/campus.rb file

Comment: I have added the campus.rb code

Comment: Add `set_table_name 'Campus'` to your `Campus` model. Or change the name of the table to `campuses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inflectors.rb` has some standard code that you can adjust for your situation:

```
# inflect.plural /^(ox)$/i, '\1en'
# inflect.singular /^(ox)en/i, '\1'
# inflect.irregular 'person', 'people'
```

So for you it should be:

```
inflect.plural /^(campus)$/i, '\1es'
inflect.singular /^(campus)es/i, '\1'
```

Or this maybe even easier:

```
inflect.irregular 'campus', 'campuses'
```

With these inflectors Rails will be looking for a table called `campuses`. Since your table name is `campus`, you have to add the following to your `Campus` model:

```
set_table_name 'campus'
```

Be sure to restart your server after making changes to `inflectors.rb`.

Comment: When I add any of these two options that you suggest, when I call for "Campus" in the console I get: => Campus(Table doesn't exist)

Comment: That's because your table name is incorrect. See my other comment above.

Comment: I tried adding set_table_name 'Campus' to campus model, but there was no change. Without the inflection I CAN access the table with "Campus"

Comment: Hm, that's strange. Are you trying this in console? You may have to restart console for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I am trying them in the console, and I close and open a new console to try the new changes.

Comment: Hm, let me try to replicate your situation... Just to be sure: the name of the table is `Campus` not `campus`?

Comment: Look, this is how I created the table:  
 create_table :campus do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :lat
      t.string :lng
      t.integer :university_id

      t.timestamps
    end

Comment: So, it is lower case. Change to `set_table_name 'campus'`. By the way, I tried this and it works.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think that would make a difference but it did. I added set_table_name 'campus' and now I can call u.campuses and Campus in the console. You are a life savior!

Comment: OK, I'll add some info to my answer. Glad I could help.