# Method_missing for relation model university.campus

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 tables: User, University and Campus.
their model is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :university
end

class Campus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :university
end

class University < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :campuses, dependent: :destroy
end
```

But I am having problems getting the campus association from university. Check this:

```
1.9.2p290 :012 > u = University.find(3)
 => #<University id: 3, name: "myuni", email: "uni.com", created_at: "2012-06-04 03:48:59", updated_at: "2012-06-13 03:22:18"> 
1.9.2p290 :013 > u.users
 => [#<User id: 21, name: "myname", email: "myemail", password: "asdfgh", created_at: "2012-08-10 23:42:40", updated_at: "2012-08-10 23:42:40", university_id: 3>] 
1.9.2p290 :014 > u.campus
NoMethodError: undefined method `campus' for #<University:0x000000031c8a10>
        from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.10/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:392:in `method_m
issing'
        from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_
missing'
        from (irb):14
        from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
        from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/mari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It might be due to the pluralization of campus, but [I haven't been able to fix that either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943432/naming-convention-in-rails-with-table-named-campus).
So I have tried u.campu, u.campuses, u.campues, but I get the same "NoMethodError".

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The relationship between university and campus is `has_many`, so it makes sense that `u.campus` doesn't work. `u.campuses` should work though. It indeed may have to do something with your pluralization problem.

Comment: Try this in the console: `u.methods.grep(/campu/)` and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that adding:

```
  set_table_name 'campus'
```

to the model: campus.rb fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would be `u.campuses` or `u.campuses.first`

I would also organize the tables as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campus
end

class Campus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :university
end

class University < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campuses, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: thanks, I get your point, but users belongs to a university (As they can attend different campuses), but I am using Campus for other tables in my DB.